# AJAX jQuery. Pulling a Date & Time field from a SharePoint List. Why is it displaying in a funky format?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

So I am pulling information from different SharePoint lists across a site to a single landing page. One of the fields I am pulling through to display on the html table is a Date & Time field (Date Submitted) is the column name. When it populates to the HTML table like I want it to, there is only one issue, the date is formatted like so: 2020-07-01T04:00:00Z.

I know a quick fix would be to just make the field a single line of text field and have the user manually enter the date, but for user experience I would much rather have it be a Date & Time field for the functionality, but this is when the formatting issues arise.

How do I get it to return so it is formatted like yyyy/mm/dd? Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you ran across is standardized, it's called the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If you want the date to be in another format, you should use some sort of conversion mechanism.

I'd recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), which would let you [parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) in just about any way that you'd like:

```js
moment('2020-07-01T04:00:00Z').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Comment: So if I am pulling from this API /items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes"), then posts through a for loop with objItems[i].Date, how would I edit that in between, I am not hard coding the Date to post into the html table.

Comment: In the case of Moment JS, you use and manipulate dates as a moment object, creating one with the constructor `moment([date data])`, which you can store into a variable or use directly. If you're simply looking to show it in the table in the format you mentioned, then just feed your API input data straight into the moment constructor and format from there: `moment(objItems[i].Date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');`.